# Probability distribution question for sequences

Tags: probability

Consider the DNA alphabet, which consists of A, C, T, G. For sequences of length 9 in the DNA alphabet, I am interested in finding the probability distribution of the number of occurrences of ATG (the start codon) provided that the sequences are drawn with probabilities corresponding to the multinomial model with parameters $pA, pC, pG, pT$ (sum of $pX$ equal to 1).

How can I approach this problem?

Comment: Can the start codone begin at a nucleotide which is not $1, 4,$ or $7$?

Comment: @philbo_baggins they can begin at any nucelotide